# Two way Audio crossover MATLAB code using Bessel

Tags: matlab, audio, lowpass-filter, highpass-filter

Could MATLAB's `besself` function be used in designing an Audio crossover (Tweeter and Woofer) with highpass and lowpass filters?

Most likely the same with [this code](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/speaker-crossover-filters.html) but using Bessel filter.